# how to fix url issue of wordpress nested subcategory archive pages

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have built a custom Wordpress theme using UnderStrap. My web site uses archive pages to display the content of all categories/subcategories. The structure is like

Parent Category > subcategory

My URL structure for archive pages is www.example.com/category/parent-category/subcategory. This is working fine but now the problem is that it is still loading the subcategory content if I use following URLs

www.example.com/category/subcategory
www.example.com/category/any-string/subcategory

Is there a way I can stop it and start displaying 404 errors?

I have tried a "redirect_canonical" filter but it's not helping at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do a couple of things to achieve what you want.

1. **Add custom rewrite rules:** First you have to add the custom rewrite rules to detect a subcategory. WordPress by default won't do that.

```
  function theme_custom_rewrites() {
    add_rewrite_tag("%parent_category_name%", "([a-z0-9\-_]+)");
    add_rewrite_rule('^category/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?', 'index.php?parent_category_name=$matches[1]&category_name=$matches[2]', 'top');

    add_rewrite_rule('^category/([a-z0-9\-_]+)/?', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]', 'top');
  }

  add_action('init', 'theme_custom_rewrites');
```

2. **Add the 404 status and template load code:**

```
function load_404_page_for_subcategory_pages() {
  global $wp_query;

  $category_slug = get_query_var('category_name');
  $parent_category_slug = get_query_var('parent_category_name');

  $parent_category = get_category_by_slug($parent_category_slug);
  $category = get_category_by_slug($category_slug);

  if( !$parent_category && $category->parent != 0) {
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header( 404 );
    get_template_part( 404 );
    exit();    
  }
}

add_action('wp', 'load_404_page_for_subcategory_pages');
```

Add both of the hooks to the functions.php file and go to the settings page on the backend and save permalinks. It should work.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. partially it did what I wanted but now it has brought another problem for me.
now when I go www.example.com/category/parent-category/subcategory it gives me the id of parent-category instead of the id of subcategory.

Comment: @AqeelAhmad Sorry about that. I didn't check the code completely. I have made changes to the code to fix that issue. Can you check if it's working for you or not?

Comment: thanks, it worked. do you have any idea why I am having this issue?  is it a bug in WordPress or I did something incorrectly? have you face this issue before that?

Comment: It's not a bug in WordPress. It's just how WordPress works. By default, WordPress tries to load a page instead of showing a 404 error as much as possible.

Comment: sorry for coming back. now I noticed this code is bringing another issue in wp-admin.

I am getting 404 when I try to filter my posts by selecting a category from dropdown.

Comment: nevermind i wrapped the code of load_404_page_for_subcategory_pages function inside "if(!is_admin())" and it worked for me

Comment: I have found a new issue with that script and i was wondering if you can help me fix that. 

problem is that now I have started getting 404 error for paginated URL. url examples are:
1- www.example.com/category/parent-category/page/5
2- www.example.com/category/parent-category/subcategory/page/5

I tried to add a conditional logic with respect to the value of "paged" query variable but I am getting incorrect value for that query variable.

Answer (score -1):

```html
function getParentsLink($category)
{
    $parent_category = get_category($category->category_parent);
    if ($parent_category->category_parent == 0) {
        return $parent_category->slug . '/' . $category->slug;
    } else {
        return getParentsLink($parent_category) . '/' . $category->slug;
    }
}


function redirect_to_correct_link()
{
    $category_slug = get_query_var('category_name');
    if ($category_slug != '') {
        $category = get_category_by_slug($category_slug);
        $parent_category = getParentsLink($category);
        $redirect = "/category/$parent_category/";
        global $wp;
        $linkToCheck = "/$wp->request/";
        if ($linkToCheck !== $redirect) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location: " . $redirect);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'redirect_to_correct_link');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).